# How to limit Bootstrap 5 container max width with SASS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, frontend

I'm new at front end and trying bootstrap,

if you look at Bootstrap 5 documentation:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/

there's a responsive table for container.
But I want it to be like this (see my red mark):

[image: max width set to 960 px]

Basically I want to limit the width to 960px no matter big the screen sizes are.

If possible I want to change Bootstrap SASS configuration rather than writing my own CSS. (which is recommended by Bootstrap)

Thank you,

Best regards

Edit: I'm using ruby on rails. command: rails new -c bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation you linked, it tells you how to override them.

Specifically this section:

Quoted from website below:

---

As shown above, Bootstrap generates a series of predefined container classes to help you build the layouts you desire. You may customize these predefined container classes by modifying the Sass map (found in _variables.scss) that powers them:

```
$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1140px,
  xxl: 1320px
);
```

---

I don't know how you integrated bootstrap into your app, but your first step is finding / exposing `_variables.scss`

Comment: so can I just delete xl and xxl? I'm using ruby on rails bootstrap

Comment: no, you should override it to the px you want. which is 960px.